# How do I make Finder snap to grid regardless of the number of items in the directory?

Tags: macos, finder

Maybe I have a case of acute OCD, I don't know - but this issue irks me more than it really should.

I set up my Finder settings to display four files or directories horizontally, snapped to a grid in which everything's symmetrical and really nice looking. However, if I don't have more than four items in the directory, the folders don't snap to to the grid like they're supposed to.

[Here's a quick fifteen second vid displaying the issue as well as the Finder settings I've used.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18187962/snaptogrid.mov)

So my question is simple: how do I fix/enable snap to grid functionality for directories with four or less items in it?

Comment: Check your link- info

Comment: I had noticed, it should be fixed - it is on my side at least.

If for some reason it's not updating for everybody, I'll repost it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18187962/snaptogrid.mov

Comment: That is a function of Window size + Icon size + Grid spacing. But since I am the opposite of OCD maybe I do not see what you mean.

Comment: Look at what happens when I delete the fifth folder and re-add it. When there are four or less files in the window, the items compress and don't snap to the same grid it does when there are five or more items in the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select "Snap to Grid" from the "Sort by" menu and "None" from the "Arrange By" menu, it'll keep the same grid spacing regardless of the number of items in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Much of apple's aesthetic design has quirks like this. Things look nice one way on a small scale and look nice in a different way on a large scale. One thing I might offer is that perhaps snap to grid is disabled if there aren't enough files to create a second row. Try resizing your window to allow five items before having to move down. Does the same thing happen? If so I think you're dealing with an inherency of the Yosemite/apple aesthetic. Sorry that it doesn't suit your tastes. They really should make the option available